# Nonlinear ODE strategy

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

I encountered the following $2^{\text{nd}}$-order, nonlinear ODE while working on a classical mechanics problem:

$$ \frac{d^2r}{dt^2}-\frac{\alpha^2}{r^3}+\beta=0 $$

where $\alpha, \beta > 0$ are given.

I'm really struggling to find an analytic solution. I tried taking the inverse Laplace Transform, but when I transformed back, I got nonsense. Any advice on a good strategy for solving this problem?

---

**Motivation**

Suppose you have a marble constrained to move along the inside surface of a cylindrical, frictionless, concave cone. Its Lagrangian is given by

$$L=\frac{m}{2}\left(\dot r^2+(r\dot\phi)^2+\dot z^2\right) -mgz+\lambda(z-r\tan(\theta))$$

where $(r,\phi,z)$ are the normal cylindrical coordinates, $\theta$ is the inclination of the cone above horizontal, and $\lambda$ is the Lagrange multiplier. Solving Lagrange's equations to eliminate $\lambda$ and rewrite $z$ in terms of $r$ gives the above equation.

Comment: There is one real constant solution.  Does that interest you?

Comment: Not really. I already knew that solution existed. It should be the limiting case of the (oscillatory) solutions that I am anticipating.

Comment: Why not to look at the problem in terms of t(r) instead of r(t) ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: the equation is second order. Unless there are other good properties that the OP can make use of, the equation for $t(r)$ will have a cubic dependence on $t'(r)$. That I don't think is exactly pleasant to deal with either.

Comment: @WillieWong. You are perfectly right. Thanks for pointing my stupidity. Cheers.

Comment: @Geoffrey: can you say a few more words about the "classical mechanics problem"? I am wondering if there are hidden conservation laws that can simplify the ODE, but those are often easier to see if one sees the original physical problem.

Comment: One method is to write it down as $d^2r/dt^2 = a^2/r^3 - b^2$ and multiply it on both sides by $dr/dt$. Then integrate both sides w.r.t $t$ You might get a lengthy expansion but you will get an oscillatory solution.

Comment: Where did you find this problem ?

Comment: If you are asking about the mathematical statement of the problem, I've edited the question to include it. If you're asking why I am interested in the problem: I was answering a related question about uniform circular motion at physics.se and I got curious about the non-uniform case.

Comment: What Torsten Hĕrculĕ Cärlemän said. With that approach, you are working the Lagrange or Hamilton formalism backward, determining the terms for kinetic and potential energy. And if the potential energy forms a well, you get oscillation.

Comment: I have been playing with that idea. I got the integral $\int\frac{rdr}{\sqrt{C_1r^2-2\beta r^3-a^2}}=t+C_2$, with $C_1$ and $C_2$ constants of integration. If you solve it in terms of the polynomial's roots (which are complex), Mathematica gets EllipticE and EllipticF functions, but I haven't found any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the $z$-coordinate with the constraint leads to the reduced Lagrangian

$$\tag{1} L~=~ \frac{\mu}{2}\dot{r}^2 +\frac{m}{2}r^2\dot{\phi}^2 -V(r),$$

where $\mu:=\frac{m}{\cos^2\theta}$ and $V(r):=mgr\tan\theta $. The canonical momenta are

$$ \tag{2} p_r~=~ \mu\dot{r}, \qquad p_{\phi}~=~mr^2\dot{\phi}. $$

Performing the Legendre transformation leads to Hamiltonian

$$ \tag{3} H~=~ \frac{p_r^2}{2\mu}+\frac{p_{\phi}^2}{2mr^2} +V(r). $$

The angular momentum $p_{\phi}$ is a constant of motion. A first integral is given by energy conservation

$$ \tag{4} E~=~ \frac{\mu}{2}\dot{r}^2 + \frac{p_{\phi}^2}{2mr^2}+V(r), $$

which leads to

$$ \tag{5} \Delta t ~=~\pm\int \frac{dr}{ \sqrt{\frac{2}{\mu}(E-\frac{p_{\phi}^2}{2mr^2}-V(r))}} .$$

Eq. (5) agrees up to signs with the integral that OP writes in a comment. We note that all orbits are radially bound. We know from [Bertrand's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_theorem) that not all radially bound orbits are closed.

Comment: It seems that we're all coming to the conclusion that this integral can be computed numerically but not in closed form. Do you agree with this? How is the general lack of closure for these orbits (per Bertram's Theorem) related to the mathematical form of the solutions? Does it imply that the anti-derivative cannot be computed analytically?